# I want to load images dynamically by using javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
var only_chapter = [["19", "2191141"], ["18", "1918042"], ["17", "1189512"], ["16", "950194"], ["15", "408357"], ["14", "58087"], ["13", "58091"], ["12", "58096"], ["11", "58103"], ["10", "58109"], ["9", "58116"], ["8", "58121"], ["7", "58128"], ["6", "58134"], ["5", "58140"], ["4", "58147"], ["3", "58153"], ["2", "58159"], ["1", "58164"]];
var chapter = 2191141;
var img_list = ["https:\/\/example.com\/upload\/zxcvbn.jpg", "https:\/\/example.com\/upload\/qwerty.jpg"];
```

If there is Javascript like this

I want to add that only_chapter like this

```html
<select class="chapter_selector">
  <option value="2191141" selected="">19</option>
  <option value="1918042">18</option>
</select>
```

and one option value same as var chapter should be shown as selected.

and img_list should be placed like this

```html
<div class="imgs">
  <img src="https://example.com/upload/zxcvbn.jpg">
  <img src="https://example.com/upload/qwerty.jpg">
</div>
```

how can i make script for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure its clear what you're asking, but I think you want to build out some HTML from your image list ?

Something like :

```
  var htmlContent = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < img_list.length; i ++) {
    htmlContent += '<img src="https://example.com/upload/"'+img_list[i]+'">'
  }
```

This `htmlContent` can then be added to your div in your html..

Without jQuery ..

```
var divImageContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("imgs");
divImageContainer[0].innerHTML = htmlContent;
```

I havent tested this, and I might have misunderstood your question.

Comment: umm if i have script like  var img_list = ["https:\/\/example.com\/upload\/zxcvbn.jpg","https:\/\/example.com\/upload\/qwerty.jpg"];
how can i list? imgs on a div which id is imgs?

Comment: @stackstack you can use the same as above, just change the img `src` to be your url from the same list..

Answer (score 0):

```js
var only_chapter = [["19","2191141"],["18","1918042"],["17","1189512"],["16","950194"],["15","408357"],["14","58087"],["13","58091"],["12","58096"],["11","58103"],["10","58109"],["9","58116"],["8","58121"],["7","58128"],["6","58134"],["5","58140"],["4","58147"],["3","58153"],["2","58159"],["1","58164"]];
var chapter = 2191141;
var img_list = ["https:\/\/example.com\/upload\/zxcvbn.jpg","https:\/\/example.com\/upload\/qwerty.jpg"];

function createSelect(array, chapter){

  var selectList = document.createElement("select");

  document.body.appendChild(selectList);

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = array[i][0];

      if(array[i][1] == chapter)
          option.setAttribute("selected", true);
      option.text = array[i][1];
      selectList.appendChild(option);
  }
}

function createIMG(Src){
  var imgElem = document.createElement("img");
  imgElem.setAttribute('src', Src);
  document.getElementsByClassName("imgs")[0].appendChild(imgElem);
}

createSelect(only_chapter, chapter);
img_list.forEach(Src => createIMG(Src))
```

```html
<div class="imgs">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```js
var b = true;
function change() {
  if (b) {
    var img = document.getElementById("myimage");
    img.src = 'https://s.yimg.com/rz/p/yahoo_frontpage_en-US_s_f_p_205x58_frontpage_2x.png';
    
    b = false;
  } else {
    var img = document.getElementById("myimage");
    img.src = 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png';
    
    b = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="imgs">
  <img id="myimage" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png">
  
<button onclick="change()">change</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var only_chapter = [
  ["19", "2191141"],
  ["18", "1918042"],
  ["17", "1189512"],
  ["16", "950194"],
  ["15", "408357"],
  ["14", "58087"],
  ["13", "58091"],
  ["12", "58096"],
  ["11", "58103"],
  ["10", "58109"],
  ["9", "58116"],
  ["8", "58121"],
  ["7", "58128"],
  ["6", "58134"],
  ["5", "58140"],
  ["4", "58147"],
  ["3", "58153"],
  ["2", "58159"],
  ["1", "58164"]
];
var chapter = 58153;
var img_list = [
  "https://example.com/upload/zxcvbn.jpg",
  "https://example.com/upload/qwerty.jpg"
];

var selectDivHtml = "";
only_chapter.forEach(element => {
  selectDivHtml += element[1] == chapter ?
    '<option value="' +
    element[1] +
    '" selected >' +
    element[0] +
    "</option>" :
    '<option value="' +
    element[1] +
    '" >' +
    element[0] +
    "</option>";

});

const selectDiv = document.getElementById("chapter_ddl");
selectDiv.innerHTML = selectDivHtml;

var imageDivHtml = "";
img_list.forEach(element => {
  imageDivHtml += '<img src="' + element + '">';
});

const imageDiv = document.getElementById("imgs");
imageDiv.innerHTML = imageDivHtml;
```

```html
<select id="chapter_ddl" class="chapter_selector"></select>


<div class="imgs" id="imgs"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can loop through arrays and concatenate values in desired format, set innerHTML of Div, like following,

```
document.getElementById("imgs").innerHTML = <concatinatedString>;
```

Comment: Apologies, I was in hurry and didn't read it properly and new to stackoverflow too.
 document.getElementsByClassName("imgs"); can be use to find element